# Ubuntu 16.04 Microfreezes ca. every second

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, freeze

First off: This is not a duplicate! I've seen the other solutions (A LOT of them) and tried them and nothing worked. Every seconds or second and a half everything to do with graphics freezes for less than a second. I can move my mouse, but there's a shadow image of where it was when the screen froze.

This doesn't affect any thing I do, except for videos and games, which I simply cannot watch/play in this state.

I've checked the system Monitor and there is no CPU spike or anything unusual during these freezes, other than the fact that the monitor doesn't move during them.

I have a HP OMEN Laptop with an i7 Core and an Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of `sudo iotop`:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance,
-- Ciarán

Comment: One possibility is that your video card, screen, or cable between them might be damaged (which is indicated by your mouse pointer appearing in two different places, which doesn't generally happen with system freezes). Another is that there's an I/O spike (try `sudo iotop` in the terminal), which can freeze a system.

Comment: How would I then get rid of I/O spikes?

Comment: It's hard to say, since that would depend on what I/O the program causing an I/O spike is trying to do. Also, Ask Ubuntu isn't like a lot of other forums. Please edit your question with the `edit` link just below it to add new details. Only answers should go in the answers section of the page.

Comment: It looks like the I/O percentage in your screenshot is really low and there's no swapping going on, so it's probably not I/O spikes, unless you see those percentages go very high.

Comment: Ok... so it's not I/O. I also corrected my posting an answer instead of an edit.

Comment: I'd look into graphical causes. It could be a hardware malfunction or something wrong with the driver or something like that. I'm not personally very knowledgeable about graphics, though.

Comment: Btw, I just realized that what Chai said about a faulty piece of hardware can't be the cause, since I have a second boot on the same pc, with windows, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**So edit after some time:** 
I have now upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and the freezes are gone. I never got rid of them completely in 16.04, but I found that part of the problem was RealPlayer (a browser add-on to download videos). I deinstalled it and the freezes got less pronounced, but they didn't completely dissapear.

Anyways... Ubuntu 18.04 seems to be more compatible with HP Omen, than 16.04.